# 'CsrfViewMiddleware' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-csrf

I am new to Django, and I just took over from another developer on this project. All I have done so far is clone the code from git and install the dependencies.

Immediately after setting up the project, and running `python manager.py runserver` and going to `localhost:8000/admin` I get an error stating the `TypeError at /admin/login/`, `'CsrfViewMiddleware' object is not iterable`:

> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/home/abhay/code/virtualenvironments/leaguesx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     39.             `response = get_response(request)`
>
> File
>   "/home/abhay/code/virtualenvironments/leaguesx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _legacy_get_response
>     249.             `response = self._get_response(request)`
>
> File
>   "/home/abhay/code/virtualenvironments/leaguesx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     217.                 `response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)`
>
> File
>   "/home/abhay/code/virtualenvironments/leaguesx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     215.                 `response = response.render()`
>
> File
>   "/home/abhay/code/virtualenvironments/leaguesx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py"
>   in render
>     109.             `self.content = self.rendered_content`
>
> File
>   "/home/abhay/code/virtualenvironments/leaguesx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/response.py"
>   in rendered_content
>     86.         `content = template.render(context, self._request)`
>
> File
>   "/home/abhay/code/virtualenvironments/leaguesx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py"
>   in render
>     66.             `return self.template.render(context)`
>
> File
>   "/home/abhay/code/virtualenvironments/leaguesx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     206.                 `with context.bind_template(self):`
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py" in `__enter__`
>     59.             `return next(self.gen)`
>
> File
>   "/home/abhay/code/virtualenvironments/leaguesx/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/context.py"
>   in bind_template
>     236.             `updates.update(processor(self.request))`
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/login/
>
> Exception Value: 'CsrfViewMiddleware' object is not iterable

[image]

I would post code from the source code but I can't figure where in the source the cause of this might possibly be.

My settings.py:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.global_settings import EMAIL_USE_SSL
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'ourapp',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'sendgrid',
    'corsheaders',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
#    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'ourapp.middleWare.authenticationMiddleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'
)

ROOT_URLCONF = ''

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
                'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

(Sorry about the lack of indentation.)
Any ideas on how to proceed from here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Rather than quoting large chunks of Django's own internal functions, please show your own code - in particular the settings file.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Done. I am sorry for the lack of detail about the source code. Just reflects my own lack of knowledge of it.

Comment: There's some sensitive information in your settings. You probably should edit it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',` from `TEMPLATES`. Probably `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',` too